# how to pull a file from android device programatically

Tags: android, database, cordova

hey i am doing a application that has a database. i need to **send a copy** of the database to my **email** as a part of my project. could anyone guide me on how to proceed ?.is it possible to pull the db file from the device using an android code ? or is the any other way to do this? i need to send all the table in the database to a mail in some format or in db so that we can restore it later. i appreciate if there is a link or a snippet to follow the process
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can copy database to sdcard & after that you can mail that.

```
public void exportDatabse(String databaseName) {

    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + getPackageName() + "//databases//" +databaseName+ "";
            String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }else{
                System.out.println(":::");
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)